# Как составить SQL запрос вывода диалогов?

Tags: php, sql, массивы

Ранее задавал вопрос как сортировать данные полученные из базы средствами PHP, посоветовали что лучше составить запрос на SQL.

Имеется таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно составить из списка сообщений - диалоги (например как в любом мессенджере, вывод только последнего сообщения от отправителя).

Получаю массив из PHP

```
[0] => Array
(
    [sender_id] => 1
    [text] => как длеа
    [date] => 1562313697
)

[1] => Array
(
    [sender_id] => 3
    [text] => тест
    [date] => 1562313674
)

[2] => Array
(
    [sender_id] => 1
    [text] => Привет
    [date] => 1562313477
)

[3] => Array
(
    [sender_id] => 2
    [text] => хай
    [date] => 1562114203
)

[4] => Array
(
    [sender_id] => 3
    [text] => 12345
    [date] => 1562113713
)

[5] => Array
(
    [sender_id] => 2
    [text] => zzz
    [date] => 1562112784
)
```

на выходе должно быть:

```
[0] => Array
(
    [sender_id] => 1
    [text] => как длеа
    [date] => 1562313697
)

[1] => Array
(
    [sender_id] => 3
    [text] => тест
    [date] => 1562313674
)

[2] => Array
(
    [sender_id] => 2
    [text] => хай
    [date] => 1562114203
)
```

Comment: почему на выходе три элемента, если должно быть только **последнее** сообщения от отправителя?

Comment: так оно и последнее, от каждого отправителя его последние сообщение

Comment: ключевое слово **от каждого**. что вы не описали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то нужно сделать группировку при выборке, с учетом последнего времени отправки:

```
    SELECT * FROM your_table as main_table 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT sender_id ,max(id) as last_message_id FROM your_table GROUP BY sender_id ) as sub_table
    ON sub_table.last_message_id = main_table.id
    ORDER BY date DESC
```

Таким образом в `sub_table` будут содержаться все последние сообщения для каждого отправителя, и из `main_table` будут браться все остальные нужные вам значение

Comment: сортировка идет по ID отправителя, а не по дате отправки.

Comment: подправил, добавил сортировку. Если вам нужна сортировка от меньшего к большему, то уберите `DESC`

Comment: Спасибо. Еще один момент, как сделать выборку сообщений только для receiver_id (определенного юзера). Или только от sender_id

Comment: добавить условие WHERE sender_id/receiver_id = *id нужный*